# Writing new lines to a text document in Android fails to add new lines

Tags: java, android, text, line-breaks

I am attempting to write some text to a text file and add a new line to it.
The only thing that shows up is the "\n".

So my text file looks like this

```
Some message.\nFrom someone\nAbout Something\nEtc etc etc\n
```

There are not line breaks.

Here is my code to append my text file. What am I doing wrong?

```
String logreport = "SOME TEXT;
try {
    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(mContext.openFileOutput(LOG_FILE_NAME, mContext.MODE_APPEND));
    outputStreamWriter.append(logreport);
    outputStreamWriter.append("\n\r");
    outputStreamWriter.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "File write failed: " + e.toString());
}
```

Comment: `outputStreamWriter.append("\n\r");`. I think that "\n" would do. And how does one see that only \n shows up??

Comment: When I open the text file I can see the \n

Comment: New line characters like \n are invisible. If you see \n then you added \\n. Or maybe its because of that \n\r.

Answer (score 0):

Try to only append the `\n`

Like: `append("\n");`